# how activate the double click and Right Click events for Kendo Grid 2023 in asp core

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-grid, razor-pages, double-click, right-click

I am a beginner in using Telerik Kendo Grid 2023 and Asp Core RazorPage, please guide me in solving this problem, how can I activate the double click and Right Click events for Kendo Grid rows, for example, I want to open a modal by double clicking on each row and modal displayed a partial view

also by rightClick show menu with meny items, this is my kendo grid codes

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<PatientVM>(Model.Patients)
     .Name("grid")
     .Pageable()
     .Sortable()
     .Filterable()
     .Scrollable()
     .Resizable(p=>p.Columns(true)) // resize the columns
     .Columns(columns =>
     {
         columns.Bound(column => column.Id).Hidden();
         columns.Bound(column => column.NationalCode).Title(@ViewBag.NationalCode);
         columns.Bound(column => column.FirstName).Title(ViewBag.FirstName);
         columns.Bound(column => column.LastName).Title(ViewBag.LastName);
         columns.Bound(columns => columns.BirthDate).Title(ViewBag.BirthDate);
         columns.Bound(column => column.Mobile).Title(ViewBag.Mobile);
     })
     .DataSource(ds => ds
     .Ajax()
     .PageSize(10)
     .ServerOperation(false)

     )
     )
```

how activate the double click and Right Click events for Kendo Grid 2023 in asp core

and how open a modal and show a view in it

please explane that how i can create partial view in asp core razor page

Thanks a lot